# different template files for product detail page of simple and grouped product types. - Magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2.2, template, simple-product, grouped-products, product-detail-page

I have 2 types of product in my website.

1) simple products and
2) grouped products

i wanted different design for both this types of product types. so how can i have different template file for product detail page for above 2 type of product.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can add different templates in 
`catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` and `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`

e.g)

Assign `one.phtml` in `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`, this `one.phtml` available only on simple products.

Assign `two.phtml` in `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`, this `two.phtml` available only on grouped products.

Comment: where to change this ?

Comment: @PradeepSanku it is a normal layout process, you can override or implement new block/template, it depends on your use cases. could you please mention which block you need to assign different templates based on product type?